# Attribute error for PersonalInfoForm

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, django-middleware

I'm a little confused why is 'clickjacking middleware` *trowing* Attribute Error on my form.

I'm making a simple application for collecting labor or user information, and I'm facing a small problem, can someone please help me and clarify what is wrong in this code

[Dpaste](http://dpaste.com/373PYDK) from my Traceback, this is my view

```
class PersonalInfoView(FormView):
    """TODO: CreateView for PersonalInfoForm
    return: TODO
    """
    template_name = 'apply_to/apply_now.html'
    form_class = PersonalInfoForm
    success_url = 'success/'

    def get(self, form, *args, **kwargs):
        """TODO: define get request
        return: TODO
        """
        self.object = None
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        return self.render_to_response(
            self.get_context_data(form=form))

    def post(self, form, *args, **kwargs):
        """TODO: Post request for PersonalInfoForm
        return: TODO
        """
        self.object = None
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_class(form)

    def form_valid(self, form, *args, **kwargs):
        """TODO: Validate form
        return: TODO
        """
        self.object = form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

    def form_invalid(self, form, *args, **kwargs):
        """TODO: handle invalid form request
        return: TODO
        """
        return self.render_to_response(
            self.get_context_data(form=form))
```

Urls

```
"""superjobs URL Configuration

the `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/
examples:
function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^$', views.home, name='home')
class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^$', Home.as_view(), name='home')
including another URLconf
    1. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

from labor_apply_app.views import PersonalInfoView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    # django-contrib-flatpages

    # url(r'^apply_to/', include('labor_apply_app.urls')),
    url(r'^$', 'labor_apply_app.views.index', name='index'),

    url(r'^apply_now/$', PersonalInfoView.as_view()),
    url(r'^success/$', TemplateView.as_view()),

    #  Django Allauth
    url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your traceback is showing that you haven't used the view above at all, but the form. Presumably you've assigned the wrong thing in urls.py.

**Edit** Actually the problem is that your post method, when the form is not valid, returns the form itself and not an HttpResponse.

However you should **not** be defining any of these methods. You are just replicating what the class-based views are already supposed to be doing for you. Make your view actually inherit from CreateView and remove all those method definitions completely.

Comment: yes, I was not including my `urls` like I should, but it is still trowing same error, where else can I look, do you want to see my form?

Comment: No, I want to see your urls.

Comment: Yes, I understand now, I was browsing django code and I see that my view is not to be defined this way